# How to create windows 10 acrylic transparency effect in Winform c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a form with support of acrylic material design.as you can see in the almost every apps of Microsoft has a transparency effect.I want to create like that.it's not impossible to do because DevExpress is already did (Fluent Form)

So anyone have the code for make windows 10 transparency effect in Winform

Comment: It is very hard and hardly worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find it particularly hard to get the acrylic effect itself in Windows Forms (see https://withinrafael.com/2015/07/08/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/), but the really hard part would be getting Win32 itself to work well with it:

[image]

Resizing the form lags the mouse cursor itself really badly, too. I'd be interested to take a look at what DevExpress does, but it looks like there's a lot more to do than to just enable acrylic. You most likely will have to custom-draw anything that goes on top of it, similar to how Aero glass was but worse because how you'll have to custom-draw the title bar and borders now, too.

#### Sample code

Warning! These are undocumented APIs. See Raymond Chen's [When programs grovel into undocumented structures…](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=41373) before proceeding.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use e.g. Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Lime) for a 50% opacity green tint.
        WindowUtils.EnableAcrylic(this, Color.Transparent);

        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    }
}
```

WindowUtils.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class WindowUtils
{
    public static void EnableAcrylic(IWin32Window window, Color blurColor)
    {
        if (window is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(window));

        var accentPolicy = new AccentPolicy
        {
            AccentState = ACCENT.ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND,
            GradientColor = ToAbgr(blurColor)
        };

        unsafe
        {
            SetWindowCompositionAttribute(
                new HandleRef(window, window.Handle),
                new WindowCompositionAttributeData
                {
                    Attribute = WCA.ACCENT_POLICY,
                    Data = &accentPolicy,
                    DataLength = Marshal.SizeOf<AccentPolicy>()
                });
        }
    }

    private static uint ToAbgr(Color color)
    {
        return ((uint)color.A << 24)
            | ((uint)color.B << 16)
            | ((uint)color.G << 8)
            | color.R;
    }

    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming, UnusedMember.Local, NotAccessedField.Local
#pragma warning disable 649

    // Discovered via:
    // https://withinrafael.com/2015/07/08/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/
    // https://github.com/riverar/sample-win32-acrylicblur/blob/917adc277c7258307799327d12262ebd47fd0308/MainWindow.xaml.cs

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(HandleRef hWnd, in WindowCompositionAttributeData data);

    private unsafe struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
    {
        public WCA Attribute;
        public void* Data;
        public int DataLength;
    }

    private enum WCA
    {
        ACCENT_POLICY = 19
    }

    private enum ACCENT
    {
        DISABLED = 0,
        ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
        ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
        ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
        ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND = 4,
        INVALID_STATE = 5
    }

    private struct AccentPolicy
    {
        public ACCENT AccentState;
        public uint AccentFlags;
        public uint GradientColor;
        public uint AnimationId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is good and I like it...but how to increase or decrease it's blur radius or blur level

Comment: @ARUNV My understanding is that if you change the blur radius and level, you're no longer doing the Acrylic style proper. In my example though, you could pass `Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Lime)` for a 50% opacity green tint.

If you want to customize things like the blur radius, I think you would have to stop relying on the system to do Acrylic. You'd probably have to set up the DirectX brushes and do tons of interop yourself.

Comment: Do you know how to use DirectX brushes for do the job...if yes please help me

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't. I think that counts as a separate question, so Stack Overflow policy is that you should open an new issue (and show your work, e.g. what did you find via web search and what happened when you tried it).

Comment: Use **WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP**  flag to avoid lag

Comment: @Castorix Thanks for the suggestion! Do you know why I wasn't able to get it to work? I just tried overridding CreateParams and returning the params with ExStyle |= 0x200000 assigned, and the mouse cursor still lags pretty far back in time when resizing.

Comment: I also tested in CreateParams and it works for me (Windows 10) :
 
`public const int WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP = 0x00200000;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP;
        return cp;
    }
}`

Comment: That's identical to my code (except that I used a local const). Ran with F5, got the same lag. I'll try again to make sure I didn't mess something up. Using GTX 1070 Ti; that wouldn't matter, would it?

Comment: @Castorix Just confirmed that the lag is present using your code verbatim inserted into my sample code above. Are you interested in figuring out what's going on? Maybe our two machines are different, e.g. I'm on 1903, or maybe we somehow have different code?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 - 1803, 17134.820. I tested in C# and C++ and I only get lag  on resizing with ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND alone. With ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND + WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP or ENABLE_BLURBEHIND alone, no lag ...

Comment: @Castorix wouldn't WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP make impossible to put controls inside the form?

Comment: With this ext. style, controls can be drawn with [DirectComposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/directcomp/directcomposition-portal)  (easier in C++)

Comment: Your warning is on point. The code doesn't work as it should since Windows 10 1903. Better to switch to UWP for that kind of things.