# Drawing visual behind a window using directx

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d, sharpdx

Is there any way to draw the content behind a window using directx.

For example: the magnifier used by windows.

I was trying to achieve the acrylic blur  effect of windows 10. What I need to do is to capture the portion behind the window and blur it using direct 2D Gaussian Blur effect.

So is there any way to get the backdrop (visual behind the window) using direct x?

**Note: i tried using magnifier api of windows and it is flickering the screen while resizing or moving the window**

Here is a sample image:

[image: Example for backdrop]

Comment: The only official way is to use Direct Composition (with it's latest version which is based on WinRT, not Win32 but still usable in any desktop app) which is integrated with Windows' dwm. Namely the CompositionBackdropBrush Class (it's a brush that contains what's "behind"). https://notes.yvt.jp/Desktop-Apps/Enabling-Backdrop-Blur

Comment: Yes I have done it earlier, i achieved the acrylic blur through this way but the problem is that when I use it in Windows 10 1903 build it totally lags the dragging and resizing of the window and even if we fix the laging it still flickers a lot.so i was trying to capture the visual behind window and manjaly blur it using direct 2d

Comment: I think you're talking about this kind of answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481230/how-to-create-windows-10-acrylic-transparency-effect-in-winform-c-sharp with undocumented functions. Indeed these don't work, lag, etc.. Using what I say is quite different and works perfectly with Windows 10 SDK 17763 and higher

Comment: Well i will check it out with the latest SDK. Since the above methods were not working i tried to use the magnifier API it works almost 50 percent.i was able to get the bitmap behind the window. any way i will keep this question open.if anyone have a better idea let them post here. Thankyou @SimonMourier